Custom tab not rendering in Teams
My static custom tab is not rendering in Teams iframe
Hi,
I've developed a custom static tab in Teams, but it's not rendering. The network tab shows no issues, and the resource is being loaded there, but it's not displaying within the Teams iframe. I've already included the necessary response headers and added the valid domains in the Teams manifest.
In response headers
content-security-policy: default-src 'self' https: http: data: blob: ;base-uri 'self' ;object-src 'none' ;script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https: http: ;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https: http: ;frame-ancestors 'self' teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com ;connect-src 'self' https: http: ws: ;
vary: origin,accept-encoding
set-cookie: session=Fe26.2**c261e64eae96688751da74ec07a91bbf99b3d0b2f72cc84c8c3a945bf86a9220*_23GcQ9LJZLITx_y22nhDA*WdMHqTQ5oD0BxzqsfSqcI6lbKWQXksEuJGtz6ZT1eiFpoa33Sakw8HJWJrGfRO-I**97955c03f8af42d4041f65ec7f93b99ba284a19310c6eaf856979a2e995d8880*DlsaUeOi8ylUEyuTRG6KhyK3lv0PW1LVK1xgTOaF5q4; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Path=/
cache-control: no-cache
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
content-encoding: gzip
Date: Fri, 09 Aug 2024 17:20:01 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Transfer-Encoding: chunked


Could you please verify the tab prerequisites mentioned in the following document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-requirements

@Nivedipa-MSFT i tried that too, added all the headers but still it is not rendering

Could you please share your manifest zip to test at our end?

Could you please share your manifest zip to test at our end?
